# Mac OSX 10.7.3 Intellij Idea 12 Android emulator crash

Tags: java, android, ios, macos, intellij-idea

I have some problems with running android emulator on mac mini.
I use Intellij Idea community edition and have this error when I try to run application.

**I/O error: Command "/Users/vladimir/Downloads/androidSdk/platform-tools/aapt package -m -J    /private/var/folders/yh/sdp_mx2n1q9263qv9gfmncr40000gn/T/android_apt_output4569562992703377997tmp -M /Users/vladimir/IdeaProjects/demoApplication/AndroidManifest.xml -S /Users/vladimir/IdeaProjects/demoApplication/res -I /Users/vladimir/Downloads/androidSdk/platforms/android-15/android.jar" execution failed with exit code 138**

I new to mac. I try to reinstall android sdk, copy and recreate application project. Try to give all permissions to project and android sdk folders. But nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and came upon your post in a search. I was using version 19 of the build tool and was able to resolve the issue by doing the following:

1. uninstalled build 19 tools via the SDK manager
2. Re-built the project using build 18 tools, instead.

This version of the build tool flagged my strings.xml resource as having an errant character in the xml. Once I removed this, the build worked again.

Hope this helps.